# Blender texturing of object is not correct

Tags: texturing

I am trying to render a simple obj model using blender. However, upon importing the obj model some of the textures are not showing. In the material properties I could see the multiple materials being assigned to the mesh. The zip file contains a screenshot for this.

I tried loading the model using Microsoft 3D builder as well as an online obj model viewer (3dviewer) and they had no issues at all displaying correct textures.  The zip file contains a screenshot for 3Dviewer.

This is my first time using blender and I am confused why a simple operation of loading an obj model is going wrong in blender. Any help in debugging this is appreciated.

The zip file also contains the 3D model itself. 
[zip file containing images and the model](https://www.dropbox.com/s/7oqfzrza20oodfs/blender_texturing_issue.zip?dl=0)

Thanks!

Comment: Please use the search box at the top of the page.  This question gets asked quite frequently: https://blender.stackexchange.com/search?q=.obj+textures

Comment: Thanks @DuarteFarrajotaRamos for your comment. I selected a mesh in the model and performed UV unwarp, but this doesn't map correctly to the texture associated with that mesh. Do I need to perform the UV unwarp and then **manually** adjust UV coordinates to apply the textures for the mesh correctly? I think Blender is able to load all the texture images properly but only few meshes in the model have correct textures. I shared the model in my original post, it would mean a lot if you could try loading it in blender, maybe I am missing something. Thank you for your time.

Comment: If your mesh was probably already unwrapped, don't unwrap again over it, or you will destroy the original coordinates fit for your texture. Either use the original coordinates, create a new UV layer, or manually adjust it to fit your texture.